# Windows RDP Questions

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a couple of questions

1. How can I connect multiple RDP sessions to the same Windows user so multiple people will use the same session and they will see what each other do like in Teamviewer or Anydesk rather than RDP making a new virtual desktop for every user?
2. How can I record an RDP session? If I start recording with a screen recorder and I close the RDP session since the virtual desktop is closed the screen recorder will record black screen.

Actually the first question wouldn't even be needed for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to figure out what I can do in my situation. I have a server that doesn't have a monitor attached to it and if I connect with an other remote software than RDP then I can't change the resolution.

Comment: “How can I connect multiple RDP sessions to the same Windows user so multiple people will use the same session” - You don’t.

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question.

Comment: Multiple RDP sessions is a Windows Server property, not available on any other Windows.

Comment: Try vnc instead

Comment: So how can I record RDP?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I connect multiple RDP sessions to the same Windows user so multiple people will use the same session and they will see what each other do like in Teamviewer or Anydesk rather than RDP making a new virtual desktop for every user?

Unfortunately, you can't - RDP opens a new "virtual desktop" for each new user. And Windows Workstation will only allow one RDP connection at a time. If you want to mirror the screen from the user who's logged into the machine you need to use a tool like Teamviewer, Anydesk, VNC, Chrome Remote Desktop, Ammyy, etc.

> How can I record an RDP session? If I start recording with a screen recorder and I close the RDP session since the virtual desktop is closed the screen recorder will record black screen.

RDP does not have an integrated "recording feature" at all, again you will need to Teamviewer, etc. for that, they have this feature build in (especially if you want the recording to end when the session is terminated).

> Actually the first question wouldn't even be needed for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to figure out what I can do in my situation. I have a server that doesn't have a monitor attached to it and if I connect with an other remote software than RDP then I can't change the resolution.

Anydesk allows you to change the resolution on the remote machine even if the monitor is disconnected at and after bootup. (at least on the current version of Win10 and Anydesk)